# Search field not pre-populated anymore in mobile view

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, top-bar

In the **"normal" (full site) view** of the Stack Exchange websites, the search field is
pre-populated from the current context. E.g. the search field on https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet is pre-populated with **"user:22656"**,
and the search field on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b
is pre-populated with **"[c++]"**.

In the **"mobile" view** (for browsers on mobile devices), the search field is
not pre-populated anymore:

[image]

(You can easily verify that by clicking on the "mobile" link at the bottom of any
page.)

I am quite sure that in previous versions of the "mobile" view, the search field
was pre-populated in the same way as it is in the "full site" view.

Is there a particular reason for this change? Could that feature be added again? I found it very convenient, e.g. when searching for an answer of a particular user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops. We were *trying* to still populate the search box, but we were looking in the wrong place for the search terms.

Will be fixed in the next build.